# How do Hall-effect sensors work in multi-pole BLDC motors?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, hall-effect

I'm somewhat confused on how Hall-effect sensing works for multi-pole BLDC motors. The Hall-effects sensors I have seen, for example in the image, often are in an arc and not evenly distributed.

I was wondering how they are really used to detect speed/direction in these applications, particularly with motors that have multiple poles.

[image]

With a single-pole motor it's straightforward, but your update is proportional to RPM and you need to detect a change in all three Hall-effect sensors to decide orientation.

With a multi-pole setup, how do you differentiate direction?

Answer (score 4):

It can be seen in this picture how the Halls are shifted against the magnets.

The leftmost Hall is in the middle of a magnet, the middle hall is on the right side of a magnet and the right hall is facing the left side of a magnet.

So once the rotor (with the magnets) is rotated, every Hall makes a pulse change at the beginning of a magnet (or at a space between magnets if you want). So all Halls together make a 120 degrees phase shift.

[image: Hall sensors on motor and magnets]

For detecting the direction you can write a truth table of Hall outputs that gives a sequence of numbers (2,3,1,5,4,6). So remember the actual number and compare it with the new number after some of the Halls change. If the sequence is going up in the truth table the motor is running in one direction; if down in the truth table the motor is running in the other direction.

[image: Table showing Hall sensor outputs for clockwise & anticlockwise rotation]

Source:

https://www.haydonkerkpittman.com/learningzone/whitepapers/connecting-brushless-dc-motors-to-electronic-controllers

Comment: Does this setup assume the spacing of the magnets is greater than the spacing of the three hall effect sensors? Ex if the poles were dense it would fail because your hall sensor would sense a different magnet?

Comment: @FourierFlux It assumes a particular sort of phase shift between them, yes. Any phase shift which keeps transitions away from each other will work, but may require flipping the truth table.

Answer (score 3):

The same way.

You only need one sensor per phase, regardless of whether each phase has one pole or multiple poles.

When you have multiple poles, it's usually simpler to group the sensors together in an arc.

---

From comments:

> How do you differentiate between multiple poles?

You don't need to differentiate between multiple poles. You just need to drive the (usually 3) phases in the correct sequence, and three sensors makes the drive circuitry ultra-simple.

> Normally you also want to detect speed and direction though?

No, there's normally no need to detect speed or direction. Direction is set by the sequencing of the phases, and it's the job of each sensor to activate the next phase when the rotor is in the correct position. The speed is determined by a number of factors, including the applied voltage and the mechanical load on the motor. The sensors make sure that the phase activations occur at the correct time, regardless of the actual speed.

Now, if you want to regulate the speed of the motor, you can use the same sensors to detect what the speed is and then provide feedback (usually by varying the applied voltage) to produce a particular speed. But that function is independent of the basic function of the sensors in driving the phases.

If you want to change the direction of the motor, that would require logic that changes the connections between the sensors and the phase drivers.

Comment: Could you explain how this works? How do you differentiate between multiple poles?

Comment: Normally you also want to detect speed and direction though?

Comment: @FourierFlux Again, you don't need to differentiate between multiple poles - The hall sensors and controller logic work exactly the same; there is no requirement knowing the number of pole-pairs from a control standpoint. As Dave already mentioned, the controller already knows how to control the direction - it's hard-coded in the logic (hardware or software). The speed is inferred from the frequency of the hall sensors. It is this part where the pole-pair matters to determine actual RPM's from the hall-sensor frequency. More pole-pairs generate more pulses per revolution.

Answer (score 0):

That image is misleading - they *should* be evenly distributed. Anyway, the Hall sensor feedback works exactly the same no matter how many pole pairs your motor has. Sure, the spacing of the Hall-sensors will get closer (all things being the same except rotor pole pairs), but the theory is exactly the same. The Hall sensors detect the position of the magnets and those signals tell the controller which phase and polarity in the stator has to be driven next. The frequency seen on those Hall sensors will scale up with the number of pole pairs (all things being equal) so the RPM calculation has to be scaled as such. Also, you only need 2 sensors to detect speed and direction (not 3).

Comment: 3 is required for direction unless you make some assumptions on speed

Comment: @FourierFlux No. Only 2 sensors are needed to detect direction and speed. No assumptions necessary as 2 sensors are the minimum required data. See "binary grey codes" for a better understanding.

Comment: How do you detect the difference between directions if you don't put an assumption on maximum rpm?

Comment: @FourierFlux I'm not sure why you think you need any assumption on the maximum RPM. That's completely irrelevant - the direction detection mechanism is completely  independent of speed. Consider the bitstream of a "quadrature encoder". That's one that uses 2 sensors to detect direction (again, independent of speed). Now change the direction. The bitstream reverses. These forward and reverse bitstreams can be decoded to figure out direction. Speed can be figured out with only 1 sensor - its frequency goes up with rotor speed.

Comment: The third sensor is for common-mode rejection.

Comment: @Sneftel No it's not. Please post the source where you found this misinformation.

Comment: Not sure where I originally learned it, but [here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect_sensor) one source (see the section on differential sensing)

Comment: @Sneftel There's nothing on that page that supports your argument. In the BLDC motor, each one of those hall sensors is responsible for its respective phase. They are symmetrical. To say " the third sensor is for CM-rejection" is a misunderstanding of the concept or the application.